# Mysql query takes long time

Tags: mysql

Hello I have table with 500k records and folowing columns:

id, id_route, id_point, lat, lng, distance, status

I want to select id_routes which are inside radius from my defined point.

Thats no problem

```
SELECT id_route 
FROM route_path
WHERE (((lat < 48.7210 + 2.0869) AND 
        (lat > 48.7210 - 2.0869)) AND 
       ((lng < 21.2578 + 2.0869) AND 
        (lng > 21.2578 - 2.0869))) 
GROUP BY id_route
```

But according PHPmyadmin it takes 0.2s. This is pretty to much since I am going to build huge query and this is just beginning.

I have also index on id_route.

**Primary key is id, schema is MyISAM**

EXPLAIN of SELECT:

id
select_type
table
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
Extra

1
SIMPLE
route_path
ALL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
506902
Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort

How can I reduce time, I think 500K is not su much records to make it so long? Thanks

Comment: what's the schema? Waht's primary key? What's index? Did you tried checking plan?

Comment: please show the Output of EXPLAIN SELECT ...

Comment: That is an unusual 'radial distance' function! And performance benefits aside, GROUP BY is primarily for use with aggregate functions.

Comment: Primary key is id, schema is MyISAM.

Comment: @mech EXPLAIN of SELECT:

id
select_type
table
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
Extra

1
SIMPLE
route_path
ALL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
506902
Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort

Answer (score 1):

if queries takes longer time , and you have set the index properly then you need a powerful server to compute the query quickly !

Answer (score 1):

A 2-dimensional search is inherently slow.  The tools won't tell you how to improve this particular query.

You seem to have no indexes in your table??  You should at least try `INDEX(lat)`.  that will limit the effort to a stripe of about 4 degrees (in your example).  This probably includes thousands of rows.  Most of them are then eliminated by checking `lng`, but not until after fetching all of those thousands.

So, you are tempted to try `INDEX(lat, lng)` only to find that it ignores `lng`.  And perhaps it runs slower because the index is bigger.

`INDEX(lat, lng, id)` and using a subquery to find the `id`s, then doing a self-join back to the table to do the rest of the work is perhaps the simplest semi-straightforward solution.  This is slightly beneficial because that is a "covering index" for the subquery, and, although you scan thousands of rows in the *index*, you don't have to fetch many rows in the *data*.

Can it be made faster?  Yes.  However, the complexity is beyond the space available here.  See [Find the nearest 10 pizza parlors](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng).  It involves InnoDB (to get index clustering), PARTITIONs (as crude 2D indexing) and modifications to the original data (to turn lat/lng into integers for PARTITION keys).

Answer (score 0):

- Click on follwing Link to know how to improve MySQL performance

  1. [MySQL Query Analyzer](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/query.html)
  2. [MySQL performance tools](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-performance.html)